# Color based different when underlying color is different

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, blending

Currently I am toying with an idea for a website. And I was wondering if this was possible (it only would have to run on modern browsers). Any JS, CSS, canvas, server supported code is good.

[image: Made an .gif to show the idea]
The line with the icon on the right is fixed on it's position, when scrolling it stays put. The content blocks (the purple and white) scroll just like anything on a website.

Now when a part of the line and icon is over the purple content bock, the line color should be white, and when it is over a white content block, it should be gray.

Is this possible? If so, how?

edit: Perhaps unclear, when the icon part is for 50% above the purple block and for 50% above the white block, it should be matching the color there correctly too.

Comment: This is easy with JavaScript.. just have two divs with borders of the color you want, placed where you want them.  However, the JS solution isn't the cleanest.  There might be a pure CSS solution for some creative folks.

Comment: I'd try using the webkit-mask property. Try making an image that is grey at the top and white at the bottom; make the line/icon a mask of that image, and put that image at a z index of -1 or whatever so it's behind all other content. The image should scroll with the page (and the mask's color will change with the image) so you should achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Here is the link you can use: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-mask

Comment: Whomever downvoted and voted to close this question clearly hasn't read the site guidelines and should probably stop over at the Help Center:  http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @Brad I can certainly see reasons for closing. The OP hasn't shown ANY kind of effort. We are not here to make websites for people.

Answer (score 0):

It may solve your problem

```
 <div clas="mainDiv">
   <div class="greyDiv">
   </div>
   <div class="purpleDiv"></div>
   <div class="contentDiv">
     Here the large text .....
   </div>
</div>
```

Css:-

```
   .mainDiv{
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    overflow:auto;
}
.greyDiv{
    background: #fff;
    color: #ccc;
    height: 250px;
}
.purpleDiv{
    height: 250px;
   background: #956BB3;
   color: #FFF; 
}
.contentDiv{
    height: 500px;
    overflow:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;

}
```

Please see :- http://jsfiddle.net/anu1718/DnR7e/